# 301 Redirect in htaccess is appending old file name to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

I'm using 301 redirect rule in my htaccess file to redirect some old urls to new ones.  However, on a few of the redirects, the old file name is appending onto the new url so I'm getting 404 page errors on those.

For example, this is my rewrite rule

```
Redirect 301 /mtrx/motion-control/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
```

but the page that shows up is

```
http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfermotion-control
```

This is the whole .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#REDIRECTS

Redirect 301 /videos/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/videos-2
Redirect 301 /press-releases-2/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/media
Redirect 301 /mtrx/motion-control/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
Redirect 301 /mtrx/pelvis-power/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
Redirect 301 /mtrx/mtrx-score/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
Redirect 301 /mtrx/recommended-drills/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
Redirect 301 /mtrx/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like mod_alias and mod_rewrite might be interfering with each other, and possibly itself.

Keep in mind that the `Redirect` directives link two path nodes together. So if you have, say:

```
Redirect 301 /mtrx/ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
```

that statement also takes: `/mtrx/foo/bar/` and redirects it to `http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golferfoo/bar/`.

You should either switch to using `RedirectMatch` or a `RewriteRule`.

For the former:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/videos/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/videos-2
RedirectMatch 301 ^/press-releases-2/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/media
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mtrx/motion-control/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mtrx/pelvis-power/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mtrx/mtrx-score/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mtrx/recommended-drills/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mtrx/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer
```

For mod_rewrite, you **must place these rules BEFORE your wordpress rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^/?videos/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/videos-2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?press-releases-2/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/media [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?mtrx/motion-control/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?mtrx/pelvis-power/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?mtrx/mtrx-score/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?mtrx/recommended-drills/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?mtrx/?$ http://www.zerolinegolf.com/golf-mtrx-for-the-golfer [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I used the first set of rules and it worked perfectly!  Thank you for your help